# on Internet Explorer's ,when textarea bind keyup or keypress the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+Z Ctrl+Y does't work?

Tags: javascript, textarea, keypress, keyup

on Internet Explorer's  ,when textarea bind keyup or keypress that the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+Z Ctrl+Y does't work!

Like this:

http://jsbin.com/ivaca

the second textarea,How to fix this bug in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this code in your page. I seems to do nothing, but I that is the problem. (I tried it on my computer - running the page without this block - works fine)

```
Event.on('el-b', 'keypress', function(e) {
    var el = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    document.body.removeChild(el);
});
```